# How to solve issue of path of any photo in gallery for kitkat and further versions?

Tags: android, android-gallery

> I used this onActivityResult method to fetch photo from Gallery or camera

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == 0) {
            finish();
            photoFile = null;
            theftimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.camera);
        }
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
            theftimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setPic();
    }

    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

            // Get the url from data
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                // Get the path from the Uri
                String path; //= getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                path = ImageFilePath.getPath(getApplicationContext(), selectedImageUri);
                String filename=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                etFileName.setText(filename);
                Log.i(TAG, "Image Path : " + path);
                // Set the image in ImageView
                theftimage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));

            }
        }
    }

}
```

> and its method for fetching path

```
public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String res = null;
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            res = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return contentUri.getPath();
    }
```

> error is

```
02-28 11:00:18.488: E/HAL(24576): hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc
02-28 11:00:18.488: E/HAL(24576): hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc
```

> its giving me error of path in kitkat and further versions. Can you solve this? Help will be appriciated.

Comment: Why are you making yourself in trouble? Uri class having inbuilt file path function. uri.getPath(). that's. it will return path of the file.

Comment: thnx!!! it work well

Comment: Sounds great.. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a path if all that you want is putting the selected file in a ImageView.

One statement will do for all Android versions:

```
theftimage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
    getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                String imgDecodableString;
                if(cursor==null) {
                    imgDecodableString= selectedImage.getPath();
                }
                else {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                }
}
```

`imgDecodableString` will contain the final path of the image and you can set the picture in your ImageView as :

```
theftimage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
```